# Read some specific lines from a big file in python

Tags: python-3.x, file, line

I want to read some specific lines from a large text file where line numbers are in a list, for example:
list_Of_line =[3991, 3992, ...]. I want to check whether there is the string "this city" in line number 3991, 3992,... or not. I want to directly access those lines. How can I do this in python?
*Text_File is like below*

```
Line_No
......................
3990   It is a big city.
3991   I live in this city.
3992   I love this city.
.......................
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "directly access" a specific number of line of a file outright, since lines can start at any position and can be of any lengths. The only way to know where each line is in a file is therefore by reading every character of the file to locate each newline character.

Understanding that, you can iterate through a given file object to build a list of file positions of the end of each line by calling the `tell` method of the file object, so that you can then "directly access" any line number you want with the `seek` method of the file object to read the specific line:

```
list_of_lines = [3991, 3992]
with open('file.txt') as file:
    positions = [0, *(file.tell() for line in file)]
    for line_number in list_of_lines:
        file.seek(positions[line_number - 1])
        if 'this city' in next(file):
            print(f"'this city' found in line #{line_number}")
```